# Curve_Fit function Doesn't seem to work. I have my xdata and ydata in arrays of same length but the curve fit gives errors. What's my mistake?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import sympy as sym

japanstats = pd.read_csv("JapanCorona.csv")

def func (x,m,s):
    expo = -(x-m)**2 / (2*s**2)
    return (1/(s*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*(math.exp(expo))

xdata = japanstats.Date
ydata = japanstats.NewCases


popt,pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error it is giving you. Have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Also, we need access to the data .. `JapanCorona.csv`

Comment: no need for math if you import numpy.